# Parsing error: Missing initializer in const declaration

Tags: typescript

I am stuck at this warning in typescript and it is not making sense to me.

```
// Styles
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
import "vuetify/styles";

// Vuetify
import { createVuetify, ThemeDefinition } from "vuetify";

const customDarkTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
  colors: {
    background: "#000000",
    surface: "#000000",
    primary: "#ec008c",
  },
};
```

This is the file I am working with and I am getting an error `Parsing error: Missing initializer in const declaration. (8:21)eslint` on line `const customDarkTheme: ThemeDefinition`

This is my **.eslintrc.json** that handles the extensions etc.

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  },
};
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's an eslint warning, not a typescript warning. Are you certain you've correctly configured eslint to support typescript? It looks to me that it might think it's JS not TS.

Comment: I have this in my setting.json for vscode `"eslint.validate": ["javascript", "vue", "typescript"]`

Comment: eslint has it's own configuration and packages. This is not a VSCode thing.

Comment: I have the tsconfig.json as well that I edited but it does not make a difference there.

Comment: That's the typescript configuration file. You need to have correct eslint configuration. That's a separate file. Look for 'eslint + typescript' tutorials to get started.

Comment: I have another file called `.eslintrc.js` I believe that is where I need to make changes? Attaching the details in the question.

Comment: Yes, that's the right configuration. You currently _don't_ have Typescript support configured in that file. This is what you will need to add.

Comment: Ahh, I am so sorry. How will I add the typescript config?

Comment: What research have you done? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I thought adding the parser info and prettier info will make it work.